# Generic variadic argument in Go?

Tags: go, variadic-functions

I know that Go doesn't support templates or overloaded functions, but I'm wondering if there's any way to do some kind of generic programming for variadic functions anyway?

I have many functions such as these:

```
func (this Document) GetString(name string, defaults ...string) string {
    v, ok := this.GetValueFromDb(name)
    if !ok {
        if len(defaults) >= 1 {
            return defaults[0]
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
    return v.asString
}

func (this Document) GetInt(name string, defaults ...int) int {
    v, ok := this.GetValueFromDb(name)
    if !ok {
        if len(defaults) >= 1 {
            return defaults[0]
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
    return v.asInt
}

// etc. for many different types
```

Is there any way to do this without having so much redundant code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most of what you can achieve is usage of `interface{}` type, something like this:

```
func (this Document) Get(name string, defaults ...interface{}) interface{} {
    v, ok := this.GetValueFromDb(name)
    if !ok {
        if len(defaults) >= 1 {
            return defaults[0]
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
    return v
}
```

`GetValueFromDb` function should also be tweaked to return `interface{}` value and not some wrapper like now.

Then in the client code you can do the following:

```
value := document.Get("index", 1).(int)  // Panics when the value is not int
```

or

```
value, ok := document.Get("index", 1).(int)  // ok is false if the value is not int
```

This will yield some runtime overhead though. I'd better stick with separate functions and try to restructure the code somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [working example](http://play.golang.org/p/BtcZob4IVo) of how you could change your code.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
)

type Document struct{
    getSucceeds bool
}

func (d *Document) GetValueFromDb(name string) (interface{}, bool) {
    return 1, d.getSucceeds
}

func (this Document) Get(name string, def ...int) interface{} {
    v, ok := this.GetValueFromDb(name)
    if !ok {
        if len(def) >= 1 {
            return def[0]
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
    return v
}

func main() {
    d1 := Document{true}
    d2 := Document{false}
    
    var int1, int2 int
    
    int1 = d1.Get("foo", 2).(int)
    int2 = d2.Get("foo", 2).(int)
    
    fmt.Println(int1, int2)
}
```

Since you know what type you expect for the given name, you can write your Get method in a generic way, returning `interface{}`, and then assert the type at the call site. See the spec about [type assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

There are different ways to emulate some aspects of generics in Go. There were lots of discussions on the mailing list. Often, there's a way to restructure code so it's less dependent on generics.

Answer (score 0):

In the client code you can do like this :

```
res := GetValue("name", 1, 2, 3)
// or
// res := GetValue("name", "one", "two", "three")

if value, ok := res.(int); ok {
    // process int return value
} else if value, ok := res.(string); ok {
    // process string return value
}

// or
// res.(type) expression only work in switch statement
// and 'res' variable's type have to be interface type
switch value := res.(type) {
case int:
    // process int return value
case string:
    // process string return value
}
```