# Generic Functions in Go

Tags: generics, go, interface

I'm in the process of learning `Go` and the documentation and interactive lessons say that an empty `interface` can hold any type, as it requires no additionally implemented methods.

So for an example:

```
func describe(i interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("Type: %T | Value: %v\n", i, i)
}
```

...would print out...

```
"Type: int | Value: 5" // for i := 5
"Type: string | Value: test" // for i := "test"
... etc
```

So I guess my question is if this is `Go's` way of implementing generic functions or if there is another, more suitable, way of doing them.

Comment: Go doesn't have true generics so this is a way around it. This system breaks down though when you have to do type assertions to extract data from composite types or enforce other rules.

Comment: @squiguy so to achieve a quasi-generic, you essentially use empty interfaces with type switches?

Comment: It's hard to say that's 100% correct, but that's one way. Unless you absolutely want to do that I would try and avoid it.

Comment: Please see @mayank's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64189246/1542187). There is now a draft proposal for Generics in Go

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Go paradigm is generally to avoid this by implementing the behavior in non-empty interfaces.  For example, say you wanted to print something with type-specific formatting:

```
func Print(i interface{}) {
    switch o := i.(type) {
        case int64:
            fmt.Printf("%5d\n", o)
        case float64:
            fmt.Printf("%7.3f\n", o)
        case string:
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", o)
        default: // covers structs and such
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", o)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could define an interface for things that know how to string themselves (this exists in the base library as an `fmt.Stringer`), and use that:

```
type Stringer interface {
    String() string
}

func Print(o Stringer) {
    fmt.Println(o.String())
}

type Foo struct {
    a, b int
}

func (f Foo) String() string {
    // Let's use a custom output format that differs from %+v
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d(%d)", f.a, f.b) 
}

type Bar struct {
    t bool
}

func (b Bar) String() string {
    if b.t {
        return "TRUE! =D"
    }
    return "false =("
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Ez6Hez6cAv

This lets you have a generic-like functionality, but still retain type safety and have the behavior itself defined *by the types*, rather than your generic function.

Go encourages you to think of types in this way, based on their behavior, what they can *do* rather than what they *contain*.

Answer (score 27):

As of Go 1.18 you can write a generic function `Print` as below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// T can be any type
func Print[T any](s []T) {
    for _, v := range s {
        fmt.Print(v)
    }
}

func main() {
    // Passing list of string works
    Print([]string{"Hello, ", "world\n"})

    // You can pass a list of int to the same function as well
    Print([]int{1, 2})
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, world
12
```

Comment: An important development +1. I mention something similar. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63353886/12817546

Answer (score 1):

Golang doesn't have a generic type, so the way you get around this is passing `interface` type and using type switches within the function.

Comment: no need for type switches ... see the 2nd half of answer by @Kaedys